# Preventing duplicate records in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Can anyone tell me how to prevent duplicate records in Firebase? I've tried using security rules. The following did not work for me:

".write": "!data.exists()"

That method only caused me to not be able to write to my database at all.

Comment: !data.exists() works wonderfully for this purpose. You'll need to be a bit more specific. Most likely, you've put it on the wrong level (e.g. root instead of the child path)

Comment: Thanks Kato, I check to see if I added these permissions at the wrong level. If that doesn't work, I'll post a more specific definition of the problem.